# problem with appserv-win32-2.5.10?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an error with appserv-win32-2.5.10 (localhost). I am new to appserv. The error message is **"The requested URL /xxxxfile.html was not found on this server**. I'm tired to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the error message says what the problem is: a file is missing.

**Solution:**
Find out what the document root of your server is, and place in this directory a file called: `xxxxfile.html`, this will solve the error msg.

Comment: hi i want the mode_rewrite enabling procedure of appserv if you plz

Comment: Please ask this as a new question! My answer is the answer for your problem above.

Comment: The requested URL /gifts/01_Mothers_Day_Gifts_to_Pakistan.php was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your files to the public folder *C:\AppServ\www*
Also check if your appserv is working properly by typing *http://localhost* in your browser.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're bumping a horrible six year old question.

Comment: Really sorry didn't realize the date.